# How to redirect all query string url in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I wanto to redirect **all url that contains query string (?)** to url before the query string in Nginx.

Example:

```
example.com?asd to example.com
```

> **example.com/?qwe** to **example.com/**

```
example.com/post-one?pod to example.com/post-one
```

> **example.com/post-one/?sadh** to **example.com/post-one/**

```
example.com/hi/there?kjg to example.com/hi/there
```

> **example.com/hi/there/buddy?jbdg** to **example.com/hi/there/buddy**

```
example.com/hi/there/buddy/?asgasg to example.com/hi/there/buddy/
```

thanks.

update:
found this solution:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\?) {
   return 301 /$1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you added is inefficient as it involves evaluating a regex statement for every request, followed by a rewrite and a second evaluation of your regex for any requests which match the first time around.

It's much simpler than that to do it properly. In Nginx the `$args` variable hold the query string, so if you are just trying to drop the query every time you just add this line to your config:

`set $args '';`

That's it. No more query strings.